# Django startapp workflow with docker

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I am confused with how to work with Django apps (create/using) when using Docker. Some of the tutorials suggest using command startapp after starting the web docker container (I'm using docker-compose to up the containers). But since the files are created inside that container, how do I go about adding code to that from my local dev machine? and moreover, this does not seem right to create apps like this to edit code...

I've been using this following structure as is so far which starts up the container and works fine. But with just one "app" which is todo
(taken from https://github.com/realpython/dockerizing-django)

```
.
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yml
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── sites-enabled
│       └── django_project
├── production.yml
├── tmp.json
└── web
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── Pipfile
    ├── Pipfile.lock
    ├── docker_django
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── apps
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── todo
    │   │       ├── __init__.py
    │   │       ├── admin.py
    │   │       ├── models.py
    │   │       ├── static
    │   │       │   └── main.css
    │   │       ├── templates
    │   │       │   ├── _base.html
    │   │       │   ├── dashboard.html
    │   │       │   └── home.html
    │   │       ├── tests.py
    │   │       ├── urls.py
    │   │       └── views.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── shell-script.sh
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_env_settings.py
```

When I use the above structure, I am not able to create apps locally as we have to use manage.py to create apps, but I need to navigate to apps folder to do that but manage.py is not accessible. So, I try to give full abs path to manage.py, but it complains about SeTTINGS_MODULE SECRET_KEY error.

What is the proper way to work with django apps when using Docker-Compose?

Do I need to change the above structure? or should I change my workflow?

EDIT:

my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    volumes:
      - web-django:/usr/src/app
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
    links:
      - web:web

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  pgadmin:
    restart: always
    image: fenglc/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    volumes:
      - pgadmindata:/var/lib/pgadmin/data/
    environment:
      DEFAULT_USER: 'pgadmin4@pgadmin.org'
      DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 'admin'

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

volumes:
  web-django:
  web-static:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
  pgadmindata:
```

My Dockerfile inside web folder:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Set environment variables

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD Pipfile /usr/src/app
ADD Pipfile.lock /usr/src/app

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN python -m pip install pipenv

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pipenv install --system

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you structure is correct. what you are looking for is a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), to make your django project on the host to be available inside the container, you can create whatever you like in your project, and the changes will take effect on the container.

**for example:**

the structure is :

```
.
├── django
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── entireDjangoAppFiles
└── docker-compose.yml
```

say this is my django dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install Django psycopg2
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and my docker compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  django:
    build:
      context: django
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - "./django:/code"
```

now any change i do in my django directory will be applied to the container's `/code` dir as well

**EDIT**

our docker-compose files are not similar... you are using [named volumes](https://success.docker.com/article/different-types-of-volumes) 
instead of usual mounting. those volumes are being created docker own volumes directory and the containers can use them, but nothing tell docker that you want those volume to contain your apps- so they are empty. to fix this, you may just remove them from the `volumes` option in your docker-compose, and prefer mount-volumes:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    volumes:
      - .web:/usr/src/app #mount the project dir
      - .path/to/static/files/dir:/usr/src/app/static #mount the static files dir
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
    links:
      - web:web

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  pgadmin:
    restart: always
    image: fenglc/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    volumes:
      - pgadmindata:/var/lib/pgadmin/data/
    environment:
      DEFAULT_USER: 'pgadmin4@pgadmin.org'
      DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 'admin'

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

volumes:
  #web-django:
  #web-static:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
  pgadmindata:
```

a note about the other named volumes - if you wondered why do you have to use them - they are the databases volumes, which supposed to be populated by the containers.

Comment: I've added my Dockerfile and docker-compose file which I believe is smiliar to what you were suggesting. But when I run this : docker-compose exec web /usr/local/bin/python manage.py startapp another_todo , I see no error, but cannot see any folders created as well with : docker-compose exec web ls docker_                                                django/apps . Only todo folder from original code

Comment: ok. It is creating it in the container in the root. But the issue still persists, when I look at the dir on the host, I dont see them

Comment: @vkk07 i think ive spotted your issue. take a look at my edit